# What does it mean [Cores 4] [Logical/Core 2]?

Tags: intel-core-i7, multi-core

I saw a Processor which states: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz[Cores 4] [**Logical/Core 2**]
It means it has 4 cores or 2 cores and and logical? I am a bit confused about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have a CPU with 4 cores and two logical threads per core, i.e. 8 threads.

Comment: Is it considered a fast processor?

Comment: It's all relative, so is it fast relative to what? It's pretty good for a low power quad-core 15W laptop CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU i7-10510U, supports Hypertheading technology. It has 4 full cores (hardware) in the chip as per [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196449/intel-core-i7-10510u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html). As each core supports 2 threads (software), you can run 8 threads.